# cannot cast to subclass when serialize/deserialize using gson

Tags: java, android, serialization, gson

I defined a Record class with an ArrayList variable, which stores a list of instances of the Base class(the instances are actually of Sub class).

sample code

```
public class Record {
  private ArrayList<Base> list;
 
  public void Record() {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
  }
  public add(Base instance) {
    list.add(instance) // instance is of Sub class
  }

  private class Sub extends Base {}
}
```

And I used the gson lib to serialize it to shared preferences

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    editor.putString(KEY, gson.toJson(record)); // an Arraylist of Record instances
    editor.commit();
```

but when deserialize it back to the ArrayList of Record instances and trying to call methods of the  Sub class from the instances in the list by casting it to the Sub class, I got error like " java.lang.ClassCastException: class Base cannot be cast to class Sub"

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<TreeMap<String, Record>>() {}.getType();
TreeMap<String, Record> records = gson.fromJson(sharedPreferences.getString(RECORDS_KEY, null), type);

// trying to call the method from the subclass
((Sub)records.get("a").list[0]).methodFromSub();
```

Comment: This is probably the expected behavior. When you tell Gson to deserialize as `Base`, and have not specified a custom adapter, then Gson will deserialize the JSON data as `Base` and will not make any assumptions whether or not the JSON data might represent data of a subclass. However, maybe it would be possible in your use case to make `Record` generic: `Record<T extends Base>`. But it would be good if you could provide more information about your use case and the data you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

Gson receive `java.lang.reflect.Type` is `TreeMap<String, Record>`, and the field `list` type in `Record` is `ArrayList<Base>`.
So gson deserialize `list` as `ArrayList<Base>`, **NOT** `ArrayList<Sub>`.
To specify `list` type to let Gson know deserialize `Sub` or `Base`, try these code:

```java
class Base {
    public String base;
}

class Record<T extends Base> {
    public ArrayList<T> list;

    public void Record() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(T instance) {
        list.add(instance); // instance is of Sub class
    }

    class Sub extends Base {

        public String sub;

        public String getBaseAndStub() {
            return (base != null ? base : "") + (sub != null ? sub : "");
        }
    }
}
```

I have test above code and it work correctly:

```java
public void test() {
    String json = "{\n" +
            "  \"haha\": {\n" +
            "    \"list\": [\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"sub\": \"sub\",\n" +
            "        \"base\": \"base\"\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    ]\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<TreeMap<String, Record<Record.Sub>>>() {}.getType();
    TreeMap<String, Record<Record.Sub>> map = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    System.out.println(map.get("haha").list.get(0).getBaseAndStub());
    // Output: basesub
}
```